# Buffer.BlockCopy vs Array.Copy curiosity

Tags: c#

I've been toying around with some .NET features (namely Pipelines, Memory, and Array Pools) for high speed file reading/parsing. I came across something interesting while playing around with `Array.Copy`, `Buffer.BlockCopy` and `ReadOnlySequence.CopyTo`. The IO Pipeline reads data as `byte` and I'm attempting to efficiently turn it into `char`.

While playing around with `Array.Copy` I found that I am able to copy from `byte[]` to `char[]` and the compiler (and runtime) are more than happy to do it.

```
char[] outputBuffer = ArrayPool<char>.Shared.Rent(inputBuffer.Length);
Array.Copy(buffer, 0, outputBuffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

This code runs as expected, though I'm sure there are some UTF edge cases not properly handled here.

My curiosity comes with `Buffer.BlockCopy`

```
char[] outputBuffer = ArrayPool<char>.Shared.Rent(inputBuffer.Length);
Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, outputBuffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

The resulting contents of `outputBuffer` are garbage. For example, with the example contents of `buffer` as

```
{ 50, 48, 49, 56, 45 }
```

The contents of `outputBuffer` after the copy is

```
{ 12338, 14385, 12333, 11575, 14385 }
```

I'm just curious what is happening "under the hood" inside the CLR that is causing these 2 commands to output such different results.

Comment: Call Array.Clear before you copy, then the problem will become evident immediately.

Comment: As usual, what looks like garbage in decimal makes sense in hexadecimal

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Array.Copy() is smarter about the element type.  It will *try* to use the memmove() CRT function when it can.  But will fall back to a loop that copies each element when it can't.  Converting them as necessary, it considers boxing and primitive type conversions.  So one element in the source array will become one element in the destination array.

Buffer.BlockCopy() skips all that and blasts with memmove().  No conversions are considered.  Which is why it can be slightly faster.  And easier to mislead you about the array content.  Do note that utf8 encoded character data is visible in that array, 12338 == 0x3032 = "2 ", 14385 = 0x3831 = "18", etc.  Easier to see with Debug > Windows > Memory > Memory 1.

Noteworthy perhaps is that this type-coercion *is* a feature.  Say when you receive an int[] through a socket or pipe but have the data in a byte[] buffer.  By far the fastest way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the insight!